# Android webview : webcoreglue Should not happen no rect-based-test nodes found blank page stack

Tags: android, webview

The issue appear when i try to upload an image to my web view and here the issue appeared with a blank page.

i tried this ligne of code but i got always the same problem

```
webview.onScrollChanged(webview.getScrollX(), webview.getScrollY());
```